# @inherhits in razor files with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to use a custom base class for my razor files in ASP.NET Core 3.1 by using `@inherits` in the cshtml file. Unfortunately Visual Studio 2019 as well as msbuild do not recognize, that a custom base class is used. I need to use this within a website, that I want to port from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET Core 3.1. With .NET 4.6.1 and ASP.NET this is working.

Here is a really simple example. My base class looks like this:

```
// Really simple base class just for demonstration purposes
public abstract class ViewBase
{
    public MyHtmlHelper Html { get; } = new MyHtmlHelper();
    
    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync();

    // Just to make the compiler happy
    public void WriteLiteral(string v) { }
    public void Write(string v) { }
}

public class MyHtmlHelper
{
    public string Checkbox() => "";        
}
```

Whereas my cshtml file looks like this:

```
@inherits Example.ViewBase
@this.Html.CheckBox()
```

The following image shows that Visual Studio does not understand that this view should be derived from the base class `Example.ViewBase`. The Property `Html` should be of type `MyHtmlHelper`, but it is showing `IHtmlHelper<dynamic>` instead.

[image: The property Html is not recognized correctly]

Also the method `Checkbox` is not recognized correctly.

[image]

When compiling this, the following error is shown:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'expression' of 'IHtmlHelper.CheckBox(string, bool?, object)'

It seems to me that with ASP.NET Core 3.1 razor views are tied to specific base class (of MVC?). Is that correct? Is there a way to properly use a custom base class with support by the editor?